# How to build a proper translation glossary for a software product?

Tags: localization, translation, glossary

There are many platforms for translation software applications that allow **community collaboration** but there is still the question on how to create and maintain a translation glossary.

It is highly recommended to create a glossary before starting to translate an application, a glossary that would contain the most common terms.

**I would like to know if there is any solution that would help a community to build and maintain a translation glossary?**

This is something similar to StackOverflow, a place where someone adds a term (question) and where others are proposing translations (answers) and vote them. The difference would be that accepting an answer would be reserved only to moderators or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend TermWiki, particularly its my glossary feature - http://www.termwiki.com/TWSpecial:My_Glossary.

Answer (score 0):

There are already opensource projects that started this initiative

Rosetta - Ubuntu translation platform https://launchpad.net/

OpenOffice.org Localization Project http://l10n.openoffice.org/

Comment: I was asking about glossary, and I am aware about these two platform but I was not able to locate any collaborative glossary.

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea Can you please explain what do you mean by glossary? Are you looking for something like this http://www.babel-linguistics.com/glossaries.htm

Answer (score 0):

TermWiki is a community oriented, wiki-based tool, with the purpose of collaborating on terminology: [www.termwiki.com](http://www.termwiki.com)

Another option is Google's translator toolkit which supports both online translation memories and online glossaries: [translate.google.com/support/toolkit](http://translate.google.com/support/toolkit/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147809)